# LDAP authentication in Django

Tags: django

I'm very new to Django and LDAP ... any help is is appreciated.

So i'm trying to setup and ldaps in Django. I'm trying to follow this (http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/) instruction, but i have few questions ...

1. Where is AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS located? So that i can add django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend
2. Where is AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI?

If i get the solutions to these i maybe able to figure out the rest ...

Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Answer (score 4):

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS should be located in your settings.py. This is where almost all configuration is done.

For AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI, I think you need to add this as a global variable to your settings.py.

You may also take a quick look at the [example configuration](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#example-configuration) on the page you referred to.

---

**EDIT**

You are right, those variables are not present in the initial `settings.py`. You need to add the following to your settings.py:

```
# Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
# superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"  # replace by the real URI
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't see AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in my settings.py. Is there more than one settings.py?

Comment: You are right, please see the edited answer above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks cyroxx!

I noticed that http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#auth-ldap-bind-dn is not exactly what i need....i need authentication against ssl....any good documentation on that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe something like the following? http://www.djm.org.uk/using-django-auth-ldap-active-directory-ldaps/

Comment: You might want to read this section in the django-auth-ldap documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/authentication.html#notes


`By default, LDAP connections are unencrypted and make no attempt to protect sensitive information, such as passwords. When communicating with an LDAP server on localhost or on a local network, this might be fine. If you need a secure connection to the LDAP server, you can either use an ldaps:// URL or enable the StartTLS extension. The latter is generally the preferred mechanism. To enable StartTLS, set AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS to True`

Comment: Let's assume that settings.py is properly configured since I can query some users from the python shell. I have a simple login.html with a username/password form. Click submit, I open a view defined in `views.py`. How do I proceed from there?